# Magento Search Product should atleast return one product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, catalogsearch

I have a one custom requirment.

In magento Search module if i am searching with any search term and result is zero then i wanted to return atleast one product (any).
if magento returns atleast result then no need to return this dummy product.

i tried following code:-

i used `controller_action_layout_render_before_catalogsearch_result_index`

```
public function customSearch($observer){
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List $block */
        $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock(self::RESULT_BLOCK_NAME);
        //echo $count = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('q'); exit;
        if ($block) {
            $collection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
            echo $collection->getSize(); exit;
            if($collection->getSize() == 0){
                $test = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getLastItem(); 
                $block->setLoadedProductCollection($test);
                exit;
               // echo "<pre>"; print_r($test->getData());
               // exit;
            }
        }
    }
```

2) In Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer

```
public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())
            ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();

        //echo Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('q'); exit;

        if(count($collection) == 0){
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in',array('34791','34790')))
                            ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addUrlRewrite();;
            //$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getLastItem(); 
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($collection);

        return $this;
    }
```

but this code is not returning the that one product when magento returns no records for any search term

Comment: Make sure your if condition satisfy, `if(count($collection) == 0)` should be `$collection->count()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be, that the `setProductCollection` Method expects a collection, but you are actually passing only the last item, which should break the method I think.

If you want to pass a collection with only one item you should try sth like this:

```
public function customSearch($observer){
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List $block */
        $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock(self::RESULT_BLOCK_NAME);
        //echo $count = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('q'); exit;
        if ($block) {
            $collection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
            echo $collection->getSize(); exit;
            if($collection->getSize() == 0){
                $test = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                             ->setPageSize(1)
                             ->setCurPage(1); 
                $block->setLoadedProductCollection($test);
            }
        }
    }
```

If this does not work you might want to try it right before the html is generated on the event `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` or in your case it should be `catalogsearch_result_index_to_html_before`

Comment: not working on all 3 observer events

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution

Copy the

`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalogsearch/result.phtml`

Move to your theme

`app/design/frontend/Your-Package/Your-Theme/template/catalogsearch/result.phtml`

```
<?php if($this->getResultCount()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <?php if ($this->helper('rss/catalog')->getTagFeedUrl()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('rss/catalog')->getTagFeedUrl() ?>" class="nobr link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1><?php echo ($this->getHeaderText() || $this->getHeaderText() === false) ? $this->getHeaderText() : $this->__("Search results for '%s'", $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText()) ?></h1>
</div>
    <?php if ($messages = $this->getNoteMessages()):?>
    <p class="note-msg">
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message):?>
            <?php echo $message?><br />
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo ($this->getHeaderText() || $this->getHeaderText() === false) ? $this->getHeaderText() : $this->__("Search results for '%s'", $this->helper('catalogsearch')->getEscapedQueryText()) ?></h1>
</div>
<p class="note-msg">
    <?php //echo ($this->getNoResultText()) ? $this->getNoResultText() : $this->__('Your search returns no results.') ?>

     //add dummy product here

    <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php if ($messages = $this->getNoteMessages()):?>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message):?>
        <br /><?php echo $message?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

May be it helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

> i used `controller_action_layout_render_before_catalogsearch_result_index`

Ok, try your first code with some fixes

```
public function customSearch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List $block */
    $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('search_result_list');

    if ($block) {

        $collection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
        if ($collection->getSize() == 0) {

            /** @var Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Collection $customCollection */
            $customCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext_collection');

            // from Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection
            $customCollection
                ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                //->addSearchFilter(Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQuery()->getQueryText())
                // add custom filtering or sorting instead of line above
                ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
                ->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->addUrlRewrite();

            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($customCollection);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($customCollection);

            // all visible custom products
            $productCount = $customCollection->getSize();

            // replace empty collection with new custom one
            $block->setCollection($customCollection);

            // used in template to show 'No results' message
            $block->getParentBlock()->setResultCount($productCount);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Add some filtering to $customCollection to show special products.

Or you can use

```
$customCollection->setPageSize(1);
$productCount = $customCollection->count(); // 1 or 0
```

to show only one product